# Show that $\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac{\ln(1-\frac1n)}{\ln n}\right)\le1-\frac1n-\frac{M}{n^s}$ for every $n$ large enough, for every $s>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let 
$$b_{n} = \frac{1}{(n-1)\ln(n-1)}\qquad \qquad \forall n\in\Bbb N.$$

I want to show that $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \leq \Big(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{M}{n^{s}}\Big)$$
for all sufficiently large $n$ and all $s>1$.

I have already shown that
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} = \Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1+\frac{\ln(1-\frac{1}{n})}{\ln{n}}\Big) \qquad \forall n\in\Bbb N.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ln(n)$ you can use fact that $lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ln^{\alpha} x}{x^k} = 0$, for all $\alpha \in R$ and $k > 0$:
This fact shows, that $ln x$ has the smallest asymptotic at $\infty$. In other words: $ln(x) \leq x^k$ for every $k > 0$ at the $\infty$. Or  $\frac{1}{ln(x)} \geq \frac{1}{x^k}$ or $ -\frac{1}{ln(x)} \leq -\frac{1}{x^k} $.

You can use Taylor series for ln:
$ln(1 - x) = -\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}$. The first item is -x, so x = $\frac{1}{n}$ and you can obtain what you need. So let's rock:

$1 - \frac{1}{n} + (1 - \frac{1}{n})(-\frac{1}{nln(n)}) - O(\frac{1}{n^2}) \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n^{1 + k}} - O(\frac{1}{n^2}) \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n^{1 + k}}$. $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ - vanishes, because its negative.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the formula.

Comment: @Pin what exactly ??

Comment: I had written (1+ln(1-1/n)/n) when it should have been (1+ln(1-1/n)/ln(n))

Comment: @duncan what about the other $\ln$? Please make the proof more comprehensive.

Comment: @Pin fixed again.

Comment: @Veliko, check it

Comment: I think it is O.K.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand all the steps in the proof. I see that substituting -1/ln(n) by -1/n would give a more positive expression. Could you explain why you substitute (1-1/n) by 1 going from the first expression to the second expression in the inequality?

Comment: @Pin, you can do $ln(n) \leq n^k $ with every $k > 0 , k \in R^+$ at the $n \to +\infty$, Hence $  - \frac{1}{ln(n)} \leq -\frac{1}{n^k}$.